# A question regarding normal and adjoint operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measurable space.

For all $f\in L^{\infty}(X,A,\mu)$ define $M_f\in B(L^2(X,A,\mu))$ by:
$M_fg:=fg$ for all $g\in L^2(X,A,\mu)$.
So, $M_f^*=M_{\overline{f}}$ and then $M_f$ is normal ($ff^*=f^*f$).
And if $f=\overline{f}$ then f is self-adjoint ($f=f^*$).

I am trying to show this theorem.
I'm not getting why is  $M_f^*=M_{\overline{f}}$.
However, if i did succeed to show this, then using the fact that:
$M_{f1}M_{f2}=M_{f1f2}$ we get:
$M_fM_f^*=M_fM_\overline{f}=M_{f\overline{f}}=M_{\overline{f}f}=M_\overline{f}M_f=M_f^*M_f$ so $M_f$ is normal (by definition).
For the second part:
If $f=\overline{f}$ then by first part we have:
$M_f^*=M_\overline{f}=M_f$ so $M_f$ is self-adjoint (by defnition).

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We show $M_f^*= M_{\overline{f}}$. I'll assume that the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is linear in the first component, i.e.
$$\langle g,h\rangle = \int_X g\overline{h}d \mu.$$

Indeed, let $g,h \in L^2(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and note that
$$\langle g, M_{\overline{f}}h\rangle = \langle g, \overline{f}h\rangle = \int_X g f\overline{h}d\mu.$$
On the other hand
$$\langle M_f g, h\rangle = \langle fg, h\rangle = \int_X fg \overline{h}d\mu$$
and thus
$$\langle g, M_{\overline{f}}h\rangle = \langle M_f g,h\rangle, \quad g,h \in L^2(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$$
so by definition of adjoint $M_f^* = M_{\overline{f}}.$

Comment: Hi @QuantumSpace what about the other part, is that fine?

Comment: @Usermat Hi. Yes, that looks completely correct!

Comment: Hi @QuantumSpace I was trying to show that $\sigma(T^*)=\overline{\sigma(T)}$ if H is a hilbert space. I was stuck with this. I know that $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ iff $T-\lambda*I$ is invertible and so $(T-\lambda*I)^*=T^*-\overline{\lambda}I$ then $\overline{\lambda} \in \sigma(T^*)$  but I am not sure how to complete from here. Can you help with that?

Comment: @Usermat Your attempt does not start too well. $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ means that $T-\lambda I$ is NOT invertible. Proceed as follows: If $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$, then $\lambda I - T$ is invertible and then also $\overline{\lambda} I - T^*$ is invertible (why?). Hence, $\overline{\lambda}\notin \sigma(T^*)$. By symmetry, we have proven that $\lambda \notin \sigma(T) \iff \overline{\lambda}\notin \sigma(T^*)$. From this, you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Yeah, i get exactly what you mentioned (though did not write it well) and did not manage to finish it..it is equivalent to say that $\lambda\in \rho(T)$ iff $\overline{\lambda} \in \rho(T^*)$ @QuantumSpace

Comment: @Usermat It follows that $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \iff \overline{\lambda}\in \sigma(T^*)$. From this, it is immediate that $\sigma(T^*) = \overline{\sigma(T)}.$

Answer (score 1):

$ \langle M_f^{*}g , h \rangle=\langle g , M_fh \rangle=\int g\overline {fh}$. This is true for all $h \in L^{2}$ so $M_f^{*}g=\overline f g=M_{\overline f} g$.